# $ Y = 1 + 2 + 3 + \dots + X $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I am looking for a way to calculate a number $ Y $ given a number $ X $ in a way similar to starting at $ 1 $ and adding all the positive whole numbers below that number including it. For example, with an $ X $ of $ 5 $, the $ Y $ would be calculated as $ 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15 $.

I need to be able to do this without going through every number below my $ X $ value to reach my answer.

I need to do this to improve the usefulness and efficiency of a noise algorithm I am working on.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple formula for that. Try to derive it yourself by writing down your sum in one row, then writing down your sum in reverse order in the second row and then adding up the numbers in every column followed by adding up these results. That must then be divided by two and should give you the right expression.
This should look something like this: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is already a way of doing this!

The formula is:

$n(n+1)/2$

So; $1 + 2 + 3 + 4...100 = 100(101)/2$ $=10100/2$ $=5050$

But perhaps my answer is too straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a famous "series" that is based from a comical story from Gauss. Perhaps you can realize what he realized that fateful day

$$1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10$$
In other words,
$$(1 + 9) + (2 + 8) + (3 + 7) + (4 + 6) + 5 + 10 = 4(10) + 5 + 10 = 5(10) + 5$$

In other words, you can always pair up numbers in $1 + 2 + .... + X$ such that their sum is equal to X! (and how many pairs can you make?)